# We didn't know what to do, so we did nothing/ were doing nothing

Tags: tenses, past-tense, simple-past, continuous-aspect

I came across this sentence in one of my workbooks:

> - We were in a difficult position. We didn't know what to do, so we *did nothing* / *were doing nothing*.

The key suggests that this should make use of the past simple, although I can't see any reason why the past continuous is not possible here (apart from the sentence at the beginning which may suggest that this is some kind of narrative – a sequence of events).

Could you tell me your views about this sentence?

I can imagine two situations:

1. We didn't know what to do, so we did nothing. – Because we couldn't figure out the solution, we simply put aside the problem.
2. We didn't know what to do, so we were doing nothing. – At that moment of the story, we were not occupied with anything (we were doing nothing).

Can the two tenses be used here, or is there something that would make the sentence incorrect if the past continuous was used?

Answer (score 1):

My spouse (German speaker originally) constantly makes this mistake.

When you say, "I was writing a letter," that is an incomplete thought.  Whenever my spouse makes a pronouncement like this, I ask, "When the storm hit?"  Think of the past progressive tense as painting a picture, a backdrop, that will make the plot development be more meaningful.

You can also use the past progressive in a nostalgic way.  But there would still be some context, for example, "When I was little, I loved to make mudpies.  When my mother was gardening on her day off, I was having fun with dirt and water too, but in my own way."

Tenses of verbs are used to make sentences, but sentences also have a context.  We don't need to use the past progressive unless there is some appropriate context.

You could check if English Language Learners has a more complete answer.